# Repository for Kdevelop (>=4.4.x)?

Tags: 12.10, kubuntu, repository, kdevelop

I need to get around a regression in the new Kdevelop (4.3.90) which is supposedly fixed in (4.4.1) but I cannot find a ppa (or other repository).  I would really rather not compile from source.  Does someone have a source for an up to date repo for Kdevelop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Kubuntu developers: http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2012/11/17/%23kubuntu-devel.html

> as per bug 1067611 we are trying to push 4.4.1 into regular 12.10,
>   however first we need to assure that this release is of sufficient
>   quality...
>
> so i tis in a separate part of the official archive called
>   'proposed'... once it has been verified that the new version works as
>   expected we can move it to from proposed to the regular archive

bug 1067611: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdevelop/+bug/1067611

Ubuntu proposed: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The PPA for kdevelop 4.4.1 are not yet published for 12.10 but you can download the .deb file from here.

- [32-bit deb package](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kdevelop/kdevelop_4.4.1-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb)
- [64 bit deb package](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kdevelop/kdevelop_4.4.1-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb)

Comment: That .deb file gives _Dependency is not satisfiable: kdevplatform6-libs (>= 1.4.1)_ in ubuntu 12.04.